# Sandboxing user sessions with systemd

Tags: systemd, sandbox

I would like to sandbox a user session on a remote Linux VM similarly as one can sandbox a systemd service. For example, in the service file I can add to `[Service]` sections lines like:

```
NoNewPrivileges=yes
PrivateDevices=yes
PrivateTmp=yes
ProtectKernelTunables=yes
ProtectSystem=strict
SystemCallFilter=...
```

I would like to do the same for any user process for the given user. Is there are a simple way to do that?

I tried to do that via creating a systemd unit with above lines that runs systemd --user. Then in sshd_config I added lines like:

```
Match User UserNameToRestrict
  ForceCommand env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/UserIdToRestrict systemd-run --user --pipe --pty /bin/bash -l
```

With this things seems work. For example, ssh to the box gives:

```
$ ssh UserNameToRestrict@my-host
Running as unit: run-u2.service
Press ^] three times within 1s to disconnect TTY.
UserNameToRestrict@my-host:~$ ping 1.1.1.
ping: socket: Operation not permitted
```

where ping was denied to gain privileges to open a raw socket due to `NoNewPrivileges` in the systemd unit file that runs the `systemd --user`.

But the whole setup looks rather complex and I am not sure it is not possible to subvert it. So perhaps there is a more straightforward approach?

Comment: The only simplification I could find is adding the same command into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and making sure that the user is unable to modify it.